# How can I drag an element within a overflow:hidden container using GSAP?

Tags: draggable, gsap

I'll try and keep it concise.

I am required to utilise the draggable plugin for GSAP in my project. The plugin is great and works really well. I think my issue is just something I'm not quite grasping.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/mhcdotcom/pen/dzyNmB

Dragging the `#stage` element allows the click and drag functionality. 
The `.inner` element extends out of the container div so I use `overflow:hidden` on the stage element. 
When I do this, the portion of the `.inner` elements that extend past the viewable area don't come in to frame and seem to be cut off.

Is there a way around this in GSAP? What am I missing?

I have googled to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Moe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"All" draggable does is add a transition to the element that is dragging, so any overflows etc will still be honoured.

I can't be 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can add classes on dragStart/dragEnd that means you should be able to get the behaviour you need.

I have forked a codepen giving you a basic example.

```
onDragStart: function() {
  stage.classList.add('dragging');
},
onDragEnd: function() {
  stage.classList.remove('dragging');
}
```

https://codepen.io/motionimaging/pen/xLxLpG